# Backdated entry created for a has_many relationship in rails with pgsql

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

I have models Post and User. Both have a has_many relationship to Post_vote.

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :post_votes, :dependent => :destroy
  ...
  def can_post_vote_for?(post)
   post_votes.build(value: 1, post: post).valid?
  end
end
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :post_votes, :dependent => :destroy
  ...
end
class PostVote < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :user
 belongs_to :post
 #validates_uniqueness_of :post_id, scope: :user_id
 validates_inclusion_of :value, in: [1, -1]
 validate :ensure_not_author

 def ensure_not_author
  errors.add :user_id, "is the author of the post" if post.user_id == user_id
 end
end
```

Now, in the post view I have

```
<% if (current_user && current_user.can_post_vote_for?(post)) || !user_signed_in? %>
 <%= link_to vote_post_path(post, value: -1),
       method: "post" do %>
 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"  style="font-size: 1.0em; font-weight: bold;"></span>
       <% end %>
       <span style="color: #888; font-weight: bold; font-size: 1.0em; margin-left: 5px;">
       <%= post.vote_up %> </span>
       <%= link_to vote_post_path(post, value: 1),
       method: "post" do %>
       <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down"  style="font-size: 1.0em;margin-left:20px; font-weight: bold;"></span>
       <% end %>
       <span style="color: #888; font-weight: bold; font-size: 1.1em; margin-left: 5px">
       <%= post.vote_down %></span>

<% end %>
```

The problem is everytime a new post is created, a post_vote is created automatically for that post by a user id 42. This doesnt happen on my local machine. Also, down vote doesnt work, failing with validaiton that entry already exists.

Could this be some kind of cache error? Issue seen only on production server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that one of the users took advantage of a missing validation and created a script to add multiple entries. After deeper inspection of the database, I contacted the user and clarified.